# New route for entry types

Tags: entry-type, routes

I would like to create a route for the entry types of a specific section, pointing to a single template.

Is it possible to do this automatically? So far I haven't had luck, I'm thinking something like this:

- route = /{ mysection.type }
- template = type/index.twig

Or would I need to create a route for each entry type and all of them pointing to same template?

- route 1 = /entryType1
- route 2 = /entryType2
- route 3 = /entryType3
- shared template = type/index.twig

The reason I would like to do it this way, as opposed to how it has been shown before, [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entry-type-urls); is because I would like to keep all the URL's with a date format, i.e.: *example.com/2014/07/11/slug* so that I can then implement an archive template. But I still need a way to filter by entry types (a total of 12 types). So that at the end of the day I end up with URLs like these ones:

- example.com/2014/01/01/**example-entry** - URL for Example Entry
- example.com/**2014/01/01/** - URL for listing entries from day
- example.com/**2014/01/** - URL for listing entries from month
- example.com/**2014/** - URL for listing entries from year
- example.com/**video/** - URL for Video types of entry
- example.com/**audio/** - URL for Audio types of entry

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have entry type specific templates for your *entry pages*, see this [docs article](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entry-type-templates) on how you can do this. And for your *archive pages*, just set a route for each of them and point it to the corresponding index/listings template.

So basically you end up with something like this for your entries:

- media/_entry.html (example.com/2014/01/01/example-entry)
- media/_types/audio.html (included in _entry.html if entry type is audio)
- media/_types/video.html (included in _entry.html if entry type is video)
- ...

and this for your archive pages:

- media/index.html (example.com/2014/01/01/ etc.)
- media/audio/index.html (example.com/audio/)
- media/video/index.html (example.com/video/)
- ...

If you don't want to set new routes for the entry type specific archive pages you can also put the templates in a folder whose index.html template file is called automatically if no route exists (eg. audio/index.html for example.com/audio/).

Additionally I'd make good use of include and extend in these templates to make this as DRY and easy to maintain as possible.

Comment: Ignore my comment. re-reading with update.

Comment: Haha, sorry, I got pretty confused. I'm not sure I'm following your suggestion but I'm gonna try it and get back. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying now. Yes, that's actually the approach I'm taking at the moment. However since I have 12 entry types, this becomes cumbersome to set up and maintain if anything changes, especially when I need to get the type name and handle, and try to keep it consistent with URLs. See this other question I posted: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/772/entry-types-custom-slug It's possible to do it this way, but it seems like there should be an easier way of handling it. Wouldn't you think?

Comment: @cballenar I don't see the problem you have with this. In case you want to add entry types, all you have to do is to add a new archive template and a new entry template. If these templates are very similar you can always work with include / extend.

Comment: @cballenar if you don't want to set new routes for the entry type specific archive pages you can also put the templates in a folder that is called automatically if no route exists (eg. audio/index.html for example.com/audio/).

Comment: Yeah, part of the problem was having to create different routes. If I had another section with even more types (I don't intend to) it would feel like a bad practice having to create a route for each. I don't have a problem with different templates, they are necessary since most of these types will look different from each other. But yeahhh... I think I'll just have to do it this way.

Comment: @cballenar see my edit / last comment on how to avoid setting up routes. You only need routes for example.com/2014/01/01/, example.com/2014/01/ and example.com/2014/ all the other templates can do with folder structure and index.html alone.